# Mean and Standard Deviation Calculator with Array

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, methods

My assignment is to create a GUI Calculator that calculates the mean, standard deviation, and keeps track of how many grades you enter using an array, methods, and while loop so you can reenter as many grades allowed.

My issue is that I *think* I have everything correctly laid out, I could be wrong because I'm newer to Java and coding in general.  My program pulls up my JOptionPane to enter grades but when I enter the grades and either try to enter a blank statement or hit cancel I get a NullPointerException which I've tried a boat load of ways to fix it with no avail.

I can't seem to exit my loop correctly and display my values in my text areas.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GradeCalculatorForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

double[] gradeArray = new double [25];
private double avg;
private double stdDeviation;     
int i;
int numElem;
double sum;
String input;


public GradeCalculatorForm() {
    initComponents();
}
/**
 *
 * @param gradeArray
 * @param numElem
 * @return
 */
public double getAverage(double[] gradeArray, int numElem){ //getAverage Method
    sum = 0;

    for(i=0;i<numElem;i++){
        sum=sum+gradeArray[i];
    }
    return (sum/numElem);
 }
/**
 *
 * @param gradeArray
 * @param numElem
 * @param avg
 * @return
 */
public double getStdDev(double[] gradeArray, int numElem, double avg){  //getStdDev method
    sum = 0;

    for(i=0;i<numElem;i++){
    sum=sum+Math.pow((gradeArray[i]-avg), 2);
}
    return Math.sqrt(sum/numElem);
}
```

My current main event code:

```
 GradeCalculatorForm grades = new GradeCalculatorForm();
   //initialize while loop
    i=0;
    while(i<25){  

      //try for NumberFormateException
      try 
      {
          //enter values into array  
     for(i=0;i<25;i++)   

         numElem = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter grade:"));
         gradeArray[i]=numElem;
         avg = grades.getAverage(gradeArray, numElem);
         stdDeviation = grades.getStdDev(gradeArray, numElem, avg);



     //over 25 values error message    
     if(i>25)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can only input 25 values!");
         }  
      }
      //catch for NumberFormatException
      catch(NumberFormatException e) 
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your input must be numeric!");
      }       
   }

         Numbertxt.setText(Double.toString(numElem));

         Meantxt.setText(Double.toString(avg));

         Stdtxt.setText(Double.toString(stdDeviation));
}
```

Again I'm fairly new to Java, Methods, and Array's in particularly.  This could be completely wrong but I've had some success with not having any syntax errors, mainly getting stuck in my own loops, exception errors, and not displaying my data correctly.  That's a lot I know.  I kinda suck at this.

EDIT: I'm stuck in my JOptionPane loop to where I can't get out without ending the entire program so I can't get a hold of any stack trace's from my errors.

EDIT*: I finally got my NPE to show up when I hit Cancel.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GradeCalculatorForm.GradesbtnActionPerformed(GradeCalculatorForm.java:168)
at GradeCalculatorForm.access$000(GradeCalculatorForm.java:9)
at GradeCalculatorForm$1.actionPerformed(GradeCalculatorForm.java:76)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I still have an issue where if hit OK in my JOptionPane when it is empty it pulls up my NumberFormatException catch message.  Advice?

Comment: Could you please update your question to include your `NullPointerException` stack trace?

Comment: I think it would be better to extend JPanel and then putting your component into a JFrame, rather than extending JFrame. But that's not related to the problem you're having.

Answer (score 2):

Take out the while loop.

Add {} in your for loop:

```
for(i=0;i<25;i++)   {
     numElem = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter grade:"));
     gradeArray[i]=numElem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using numElem for the grade that is entered and also for the control of the for loops in getAverage and getStdDev. The gradeArray has 25 elements, so if a grade of 80 is entered, those loops will try to run beyond the end of the array. An array knows its length, and you can reference it as gradeArray.length. However, you could easily support more grades by switching from an array to a List.

The loops and the test for grade entry don't make much sense. There is no reason to have a while loop around the for loop, and the if statement will never execute since `i` will be 25 by the time it is reached. Also, as M21B8 pointed out, your for loop needs braces around it. As it stands, the `JOptionPane` will be shown 25 times, and then the lines to set the entry in the array and calculate the `avg` and `stdDeviation` will run once, with `i == 25`.

However, this should cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since `gradeArray` only has 25 elements with indices from 0 to 24. There must be a separate problem causing the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to get out of loops is to use break. All you do is insert the word "break;" to wherever it's needed and boom, your loop stops.

Also, I believe you should consider having your input be a string so you can test for nonexistent and null answers.

```
if ((input != null) && (input.length() > 0)) {
```

Lastly, since these are grades make sure that none of the input is negative or 0.

Hope that helps.